# Ubuntu 16.10 Acer Swift-3 multiple problems

Tags: 16.10, acer

Hello guys im new here so sorry if i do anything wrong.

Windows is preinstalled (OEM) on my new Laptop ( Acer Sift 3 / SF314-51 )

So there are the following Problems

after installing with this tutorial ( [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) )

It all bootet up nice and smoothly i could login and then when klicking on something in desktop it crashed. Now sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't

Now i have the following problems

1. At Ubuntu loading screen it gets stuck and stays there
2. After login i have only my mouse and the desktop when pressing CTRL + ALT + T nothing happens. CTRL + ALT + F1 leads to mouse disappearing only Desktop visible after that !
3. i get a short blackscreen with the message ath10k error -2

so everything is quit messed ap
it is very rare that the desktop stays in a mode that i can open terminal but sometimes it does ! please help me .. :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, but first a little bit of backstory. I too, own one of these machines, and I was famished when I found that Ubuntu would hang and would boot 1/10 percent of the time.

The reason is the following. The Acer Swift 3 firmware and the ACPI firmware in Linux 4.11 & below have a bit of a conflict...

But the solution is this! Linux kernel Devs fixed it in Kernel 4.12 and above! Ubuntu 17.10 officially comes with the latest kernel, but it will release after a few months. so a TEMPORARY solution (not recommended by me, see below why) is to boot an Ubuntu ISO with the Mainline / unstable 4.12 or above kernel, or boot Ubuntu with acpi=off, use a separate mouse and keyboard, install the Mainline Kernels, and remove that acpi=off from the grub boot commands.

Why is this not a good solution? because Mainline kernels have many bugs and stuff, and I got harsh karma from using Mainline kernels. my new Acer Swift 3's battery total went from 100% to 98%!!! I can never charge my laptop to its full potential now! And that is to be expected in any laptop, but the reason why this is such a big problem is because the battery went down in 1 day!! within a day, the total of my new laptop took a hit. that is why I will use Linux on MY Acer Swift 3 only once Ubuntu 18.04 releases (for stability, but 17.10 will also work) But you are free to go ahead and use risky software and kernels.

LINK for Ubuntu ISO with mainline kernel -> http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/interim-ubuntu-1704-iso-with-mainline_29.html
TIP - Install That ISO, and upgrade its Mainline kernel to the latest, or at least to 4.12, because it comes with 4.12RC7. Or maybe try an "unstable" Ubuntu kernel, but be warned, battery life takes a hit when using these kernels, so remember to use TLP ;) Good Luck!