# internet connectivity issue with wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am a new user of Ubuntu. I install ubuntu 16.04 in my acer swift 3. I am connected to the wifi from my router. But sometimes i can not access Internet. It says no internet connection but the wifi is connected when i try to access any website But sometime i can browse internet without fixing or changing anything.

First i thought may be my internet connection problem. But other device connected in the same wifi works fine and no such kind of problem occurs.. Then i thought it's my laptop problem. But when I use windows in this laptop that problem not happen... So please help me,  how can i cope with this problem?

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless 
Network Adapter [11ad:0807]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 2):

add namerser in resolve and disable ipv6

vim /etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and

I think you may be suffering from a couple different issues. I want you to reinstall the Ubuntu package linux-firmware as that may be more up to date than kvallo's github site

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

A recent change to network manager enables wifi powersave by default, to disable this do

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

reboot

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are occurring due to Ubuntu having a conflict with Acer firmware. To resolve this, install using an Ubuntu ISO with a new mainline kernel, or install Ubuntu with `acpi=off`, boot it with `acpi=off`, install a mainline kernel, and boot normally without `acpi=off`.

For more details, see my answer -> [Ubuntu 16.10 Acer Swift-3 multiple problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868433/ubuntu-16-10-acer-swift-3-multiple-problems/940624#940624)